# React JS (Form Update Not Working) - How to set state immediately after getting data from API using mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am very new to react and working on some basics where I came up in the situation - I want to set state immediately after API call.

Scenario:

2 Forms:

1st form => accepts id and calls api to get data of single user

2nd form => updates data

PROBLEM: I want to set state when I get data after clicking submit button on 1st Form

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getSingleUser } from '../redux/user/userActions';

export class UsersContainerUpdate extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props.propFirstName);
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            // first_name: props.propFirstName === '' ? '' : props.propFirstName,
            first_name: props.propFirstName,
            last_name: props.propLastName === '' ? '' : props.propLastName,
            phone: props.propPhone === '' ? '' : props.propPhone,
            email: props.propEmail === '' ? '' : props.propEmail,
            address: props.propAddress === '' ? '' : props.propAddress,
            city: props.propCity === '' ? '' : props.propCity,
            state: props.propState === '' ? '' : props.propState,
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
    }


    handleChange = (field, event) => {
        this.setState({ [field]: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        // alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.name);


        event.preventDefault();
        const {
            id
        } = this.state;

        const postData = {
            id: id
        };

        // console.log(this.state);
        // console.log(postData);

        this.props.getSingleUserData(id);
        // if (this.props.getSingleUserData(id)) {
        //     this.setState({
        //         ...this.state,
        //         first_name: this.props.propFirstName
        //     });
        // }


    }

    handleUpdate(event) {
        // alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.name);
        event.preventDefault();
        const {
            first_name,
            last_name,
            phone,
            email,
            address,
            city,
            state
        } = this.state;

        const postData = {
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            phone: phone,
            email: email,
            address: address,
            city: city,
            state: state
        };

        console.log(this.state);
        console.log("POSTDATA:", postData);
        // alert('hi');
        // this.props.updateUserData(id,postData); 

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Update User By ID</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label>ID:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.id}
                            onChange={(event, newValue) => this.handleChange('id', event)}

                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <h1>Update User</h1>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleUpdate}>
                        <div>
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                value={this.state.first_name || this.props.propFirstName}
                                onChange={(event, newValue) => this.handleChange('first_name', event)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Last Name:</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                value={this.state.last_name || this.props.propLastName}
                                onChange={(event, newValue) => this.handleChange('last_name', event)} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Phone:</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                value={this.state.phone || this.props.propPhone}
                                onChange={(event, newValue) => this.handleChange('phone', event)} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                value={this.state.email || this.props.propEmail}
                                onChange={(event, newValue) => this.handleChange('email', event)} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div>
                        Notice Message : {this.props.propFirstName}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state.user);
    return {
        propFirstName: state.user.first_name,
        propLastName: state.user.last_name,
        propPhone: state.user.phone,
        propEmail: state.user.email,
        propAddress: state.user.address,
        propCity: state.user.city,
        propState: state.user.state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getSingleUserData: id => dispatch(getSingleUser(id)),
        // updateUserData: (id,postData) => dispatch(updateUser(id,postData))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UsersContainerUpdate)
```

The console outputs are

[image]

The console output of line:81 is the current state which is currently empty. I want to set it there.

Thanks in advance. Cheers!!

Comment: Migrate to function components unless you have a strong to reason to stay back and fight with class components

Comment: @Karthikeyan: Is it not possible to achieve through class components? May be you could lead the way and help me.... Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. Provided my comments as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

`state.user` is used to set the **initial value** of your component's state.  Changes to those props do not change your state after the component is created.  They *do* change the values in your inputs because the initial value was an empty string `''` so you default to showing the value from `props`.  This is very misleading since those inputs don't reflect the current state.

I bet I could delete at least half of this code but that's besides the point.  But take a moment to think about why `props.propState === '' ? '' : props.propState` is always exactly the same as just `props.propState`.

---

#### Solution

I have two key recommendations for how I would rewrite this:

1. Select user by id
2. Separate into multiple components
3. Store only the modifications in the state

---

Create a selector function `selectUserById` that selects a `user` from your Redux state by the `id`.  I don't think it makes sense to store the current user properties as top-level properties of `state.user` like you have them right now.  It seems like you also have a property `state.user.users` which is an `array` of all loaded users so I would use that.

```
const selectUserById = (state, id) => state.user.users.find(user => user.id === id);
```

Or better yet, store an object of users keyed by id.

```
const selectUserById = (state, id) => state.user.users[id];
```

With this approach we either have a complete user object or we have `undefined`.  It's easy to check for `undefined` and not show the "Update User" form at all until we have real data.  This makes more sense than using empty strings as the default.

---

We can access the complete user object from Redux.  I would not duplicate that object in state.  Instead I would use the state only for the properties that you have changed.  You would start out with the state as an empty object and add properties to it as you modify their inputs.  You can always combine the two together using object spreading.

```
const merged = {...existing, ...changes}
```

---

Can you implement these suggestions using class components and `connect`? Yes.  But why add the extra hurdle?  Some of the things in your code like `this.handleChange.bind(this)` are relics of the past when we had to do that because there wasn't a better way.  But now we have better ways so you should use them.

---

#### Code

[Interactive Demo on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-snowflake-qpjy7?file=/src/components/App.tsx)

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "../store";
import { getSingleUser, updateUser } from "../store/slice";

const selectUserById = (state, id) => state.user.users[id];

const UserIdForm = ({ submitId }) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    submitId(id);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>ID:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={id}
          onChange={(event) => setId(event.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

const UpdateUserForm = ({ id }) => {
  const [changes, setChanges] = useState > {};

  const existing = useSelector((state) => selectUserById(state, id));

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // respond to changes in id by clearing the changes state and requesting the user
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSingleUser(id));
    setChanges({});
  }, [dispatch, setChanges, id]);

  if (!existing) {
    return <div>Loading User...</div>;
  }

  const merged = { ...existing, ...changes };

  const handleChange = (property, event) => {
    // in function components you have to copy the whole state
    setChanges((prevChanges) => ({
      ...prevChanges,
      [property]: event.target.value
    }));
  };

  const handleUpdate = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const postData = { ...merged, id };
    console.log("POSTDATA:", postData);
    dispatch(updateUser(postData));
  };

  const renderInput = (property, label) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          {label}
          <input
            type="text"
            value={merged[property]} // shows the current value or the updated value
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(property, event)}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
      {renderInput("first_name", "First Name:")}
      {renderInput("last_name", "Last Name:")}
      {renderInput("phone", "Phone:")}
      {renderInput("email", "Email:")}
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

const UsersContainerUpdate = () => {
  // this is the id that was last submitted.
  const [id, setId] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Update User By ID</h1>
        <UserIdForm submitId={setId} />
      </div>
      {!!id && ( // only load when there is an actual id
        <div>
          <h1>Update User</h1>
          <UpdateUserForm id={id} />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UsersContainerUpdate;
```

Comment: I want to set state after I get data from API and I dont know how to achieve that. Maybe you could lead me the way there.

Comment: Yes I can do it but it involves some fairly significant changes so give me a few hours because I've got errands to run :)

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is just to state after API call inside this.props.getSingleUserData(id),

Approach 1: (Unclean)
Add one more argument to getSingleUserData(id, setState) and pass it this.setState as an argument and inside getSingleUserData you can set the state using the function reference passed

Approach 2:
You can return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from getSingleUserData and do setState once it is resolves

Suggestion:
Divide your big component into individual components (like one for getting user ID and one for User data updation). The more we identify and split our project into meanigfull individual components we get more clean codes. Also when you choose to move towards functional components you can reduce lot of boiler plates with hooks.